# Difference between mvn and mvn3 command

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have latest version of maven installed which is 3.0.4. A test at command line with `mvn -version` results in confirming this.

For all my maven commands I am using `mvn` but on several occasion on the internet I have seen people using `mvn3` instead what is the difference between the two commands and why I am unable to use `mvn3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like (according to [How do I install Maven 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49557)), default installation of maven 3 on Ubuntu uses `mvn3` symlink to `mvn`.

I can't find `mvn3` command neither in 3.0.3 nor in 3.0.4. I believe `mvn3` is only used to emphasize that maven 3 should be used as opposed to maven 2 (still popular). These two versions are significantly different so it's worth to make sure newer is used.